# Is Canonical/Ubuntu community compiling/offering packages for precise:armhf (12.04 LTS)?

Tags: 12.04

Ubuntu provides [Ubuntu Core 12.04 for armhf](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/12.04/release/).

*** Does Canonical/Ubuntu community compile and offer repositories with precompiled armhf packages as it is done with x86/x86_64 arch ? ***